# Magento Inline small CSS

Tags: php, javascript, ce-1.8.1.0, css, html

i analyzed my website on Gmetrix.com for for optimization and the result was this:

> The following external resources have small response bodies. Inlining
>   the response in HTML can reduce blocking of page rendering:

```
http://mysite.com/ should inline the following small resources:
http://mysite.com/media/css/38f74ae13bf9722265996c2842cba8a5.css
```

inside of CSS file:

```
*{background:none!important;text-align:right!important}html{margin:0!important;padding:0!important}body{background:#fff!important;font-size:9pt!important;padding:0!important;margin:10px!important}a{color:#2976c9!important}th,td{color:#2f2f2f!important;border-color:#ccc!important}.header-container,.nav-container,.footer-container,.pager,.toolbar,.actions,.buttons-set{display:none!important}.page-print .data-table .cart-tax-total{background-position:0 -54px}.page-print .data-table .cart-tax-info{display:block!important}.pv-top-outline .product-top-wrapper{box-shadow:none}.pv-top-outline .product-top-wrapper2{box-shadow:none}
```

> **Inline small CSS**
>
> Inlining small external CSS files can save the overhead of fetching
>   these small files. A good alternative to inline CSS is to combine the
>   external CSS files.

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Because the CSS file is generated it is hard to just put it into the body.

What you can do is hook somehow in the merging process and instead of generating a file, generate a template and add it via layout xml to your store.

Answer (score 0):

You know, the proposal of the site is a good deal but it's not so important.
I'm a Magento developer but I don't know easy way and didn't hear that someone asked me about this.

Actually, you have to update block which render all CSS files and program it that should add content of merged CSS into HEAD block directly instead add a link to the merged file.

To improve getting static files (if you didn't do this) you may set up your server (caching, nginx usage) but this is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Google PageSpeed module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) which is available for different webservers and can do such kind of things on webserver level.